# Get active members list for a subscription plan in Woocommerce subscriptions

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying with Woocommerce subscriptions to retrieve and display the active members for specific subscription plan.

I would like to get their first name, last name and billing phone, so my employees can know how is still active in easy way.

I have tried to find a way in [Woocommerce Subscriptions Developer Docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/woocommerce-subscriptions/developer-docs/) without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using a custom SQL Query.

Below the first function will make the query based on a product ID (or a variation ID) that is the targeted subscription plan.

The second function will display the results in a html table with the User Id, the billing first name, the billing last name, the billing phone and the billing email.

The code:

```
// The SQL query
function get_active_subscribers_for_plan( $product_id = 0, $variation_id = 0 ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( $variation_id > 0 ){
        $query_subscription_plan = "AND woim.meta_key = '_variation_id' AND woim.meta_value = '$variation_id'";
    } else {
        $query_subscription_plan = "AND woim.meta_key = '_product_id' AND woim.meta_value = '$product_id'";
    }

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT DISTINCT pm1.meta_value as user_id, pm2.meta_value as first_name,
        pm3.meta_value as last_name, pm4.meta_value as phone, pm5.meta_value as email
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm1 ON p.ID = pm1.post_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm2 ON p.ID = pm2.post_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm3 ON p.ID = pm3.post_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm4 ON p.ID = pm4.post_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm5 ON p.ID = pm5.post_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p2 ON p.ID = p2.post_parent
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items as woi ON p2.ID = woi.order_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as woim ON woi.order_item_id = woim.order_item_id
        WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND p2.post_type = 'shop_subscription'
        AND p2.post_status = 'wc-active'
        AND pm1.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND pm2.meta_key = '_billing_first_name'
        AND pm3.meta_key = '_billing_last_name'
        AND pm4.meta_key = '_billing_phone'
        AND pm5.meta_key = '_billing_email'
        $query_subscription_plan
    ");

    return $results;
}

// The Html Output
function display_active_subscribers_for_plan( $product_id = 0, $variation_id = 0 ){
    // The query
    $results = get_active_subscribers_for_plan( $product_id, $variation_id );

    // The display
    echo '<table>
    <thead><tr>
        <th>' . __("User ID","woocommerce") . '</th>
        <th>' . __("First name","woocommerce") . '</th>
        <th>' . __("Last name","woocommerce") . '</th>
        <th>' . __("Phone","woocommerce") . '</th>
        <th>' . __("Email","woocommerce") . '</th>
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>';
    // Loop through each subscriber
    foreach( $results as $result ){
        // Edit User Url
        $edit_user_url = home_url('/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id=' . $result->user_id . '/');

        echo '<tr>
        <td><a href="' . $edit_user_url . '">' . $result->user_id . '</a></td>
        <td>' . $result->first_name . '</td>
        <td>' . $result->last_name . '</td>
        <td>' . $result->phone . '</td>
        <td><a href="malto:' . $result->email . '">' . $result->email . '</a></td>
        </tr>';
    }
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

---

**USAGE**

**1) For a simple subscription type and a defined product ID** *(where `91` is the product ID)* :

```
display_active_subscribers_for_plan( 91 );
```

**2) For a variation subscription type and a defined variation ID** *(where `149` is the product ID)* :

```
display_active_subscribers_for_plan( 149, 'variation' );
```

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to add a custom meta field?

Comment: like the address and start and end date

Comment: Ok I will test this funcition and get back to you, so coud you confirm that it gets tha only "active" members?

Comment: @GamalElwazeery I have added this line `AND p2.post_status = 'wc-active'` which will query only active subscriptions.